# how to clear a certain content in a rich text box

Tags: vb.net

i have a rich text box that displays items.These items have column names.The column names are loaded when the form loads.They hold values as rows.These rows are appended at a click of a button (when add button is clicked).

At the bottom,let me say i have another field(total amount) in the rtb which displays total value of a Amount column.This is also displayed when calculate button is clicked.

If someone wants to add another row to be calculated it would create the format displayed.so i wanted to clear the total amount field when another item gets added.Is there a way to do that.

[image]

Comment: I'm not a VB developer at all. But i think this is a generic issue that you would have in any language. A rich text box is just a container for a string of text. Unless you use text parsing tools (i.e. regex), you cannot modify the text within it on a "element" type basis. You have to change the text string as a whole and re-render. If there is always a total box, you should split these up into separate elements, so that you can reference the total box individually. If that is impossible for whatever reason, you MUST use text manipulation

Comment: A listview would be handy here with the columns and rows(items) as separate collections manipulating the rows or individual values is quite easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Richtextbox1.text = mid(Richtextbox1.text,1,len(richtextbox1.text)-x) & NewTotal

Where x is the length of the previous total and NewTotal is the new total string.

Edit (see comments):

Use this code to solve your issue:

```
dim numberofcolumns as integer = listview1.ColumnHeaders.Count

dim str(numberofcolumns-1) as string

 str(numberofcolumns-2) = "TotalAmount"

 str(numberofcolumns-1) = totalammountvariable

Dim itm As ListViewItem

 itm = New ListViewItem(str)

 ListView1.Items.add(itm)
```

Comment: That cuts the total amount value from the richtextbox and then replaces it with the new amount. You could put that on the calculate button I suppose. To be honest though this isn't a great solution, because you're asking the wrong question. It'll take almost no time to create this formatted text using a string builder so you could just recreate it each time something is added/calculated. I assume you are concerned about the speed of the report creation (otherwise I don't know why you'd want to edit rather than recreate) but this will be less than a second for a report of almost any length.

Comment: I used a listview as another solution but i can't put the string "Total Amount" to the right of the control.

Comment: TO put it in the final column of the listview do the following: dim str(numberofcolumns-1) as string, str(numberofcolumns-2) = "TotalAmount", str(numberofcolumns-1) = totalammountvariable,   Dim itm As ListViewItem,   itm = New ListViewItem(str), ListView2.Items.add(itm)

Comment: i can't figure out the code,can you write the code separately

Comment: I'll drop it into an answer for you

Comment: str(numberofcolumns-1) and str(numberofcolumns-2) is raising an error saying numberof columns is not declared

Answer (score 0):

First Clear All Data and Rebind

```
RichTextBox1.Clear()
```

Using this Command clear all data in Richtextbox and rebind you data